# Counting Words in a Column

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, unique, histogram, counter

The video game is a FPS shooter game called PUBG.  I want to count the number of times someone died by a particular weapon.  However the items are in a column.

The game `killed_by` has a list of ways for a player to die:

```
df.(['Grenade', 'SCAR-L', 'S686', 'Down and Out', 'M416', 'Punch', 'AKM',
       'P92', 'Win94', 'M16A4', 'S12K', 'Hit by Car',
       'death.WeapSawnoff_C', 'Kar98k', 'Tommy Gun', 'S1897', 'Bluezone',
       'Micro UZI', 'P1911', 'SKS', 'Mini 14', 'Mk14', 'Falling', 'UMP9',
       'P18C', 'Machete', 'Sickle', 'Groza', 'Crossbow', 'Drown', 'Vector',
       'R1895', 'M249', 'Uaz', 'M24', 'VSS', 'Pan', 'AWM', 'RedZone',
       'Motorbike', 'Buggy', 'death.ProjMolotov_DamageField_C', 'Dacia',
       'DP-28', 'R45', 'Motorbike (SideCar)', 'death.Buff_FireDOT_C',
       'Crowbar', 'AUG', 'Van', 'Pickup Truck', 'Aquarail', 'Boat',
       'death.ProjMolotov_C', 'death.PG117_A_01_C', 'death.RedZoneBomb_C'], dtype=object).counter
```

And create a histogram using such values.

```
 df.killed_by.unique()
```

Gives:

```
File "<ipython-input-38-042a4177bd4e>", line 1
    df.(['Grenade', 'SCAR-L', 'S686', 'Down and Out', 'M416', 'Punch', 'AKM',
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please post inputs, outputs (including error messages) and code as **text** instead of screenshots and try to come up with a [mcve]. Also, please state what your **question** is.

Comment: You seem to be using some kind of DataFrame. Are those pandas Dataframes? (Py)Spark Dataframes?

Comment: It is Pandas not PySpark.

Comment: Don't you think that `pandas` is a more relevant tag than `counter` to attract people that might be able to help you with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`df.([]).counter` gives you an syntax error because you are not calling any method.

i don't know exactly what were you trying to achieve by that line of code, however if you wanna get the occurrences of each weapon this might be one of the many ways you can do it.

```
a = ['Grenade', 'SCAR-L', 'S686', 'Down and Out', 'M416', 'Punch', 'AKM',
       'P92', 'Win94', 'M16A4', 'S12K', 'Hit by Car',
       'death.WeapSawnoff_C', 'Kar98k', 'Tommy Gun', 'S1897', 'Bluezone',
       'Micro UZI', 'P1911', 'SKS', 'Mini 14', 'Mk14', 'Falling', 'UMP9',
       'P18C', 'Machete', 'Sickle', 'Groza', 'Crossbow', 'Drown', 'Vector',
       'R1895', 'M249', 'Uaz', 'M24', 'VSS', 'Pan', 'AWM', 'RedZone',
       'Motorbike', 'Buggy', 'death.ProjMolotov_DamageField_C', 'Dacia',
       'DP-28', 'R45', 'Motorbike (SideCar)', 'death.Buff_FireDOT_C',
       'Crowbar', 'AUG', 'Van', 'Pickup Truck', 'Aquarail', 'Boat',
       'death.ProjMolotov_C', 'death.PG117_A_01_C', 'death.RedZoneBomb_C']

# or select the data by pandas indexing
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(a))
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to get the sum of each kill per weapon in the column.  Only problem is I need to count every row to determine which weapons efficiency.

Comment: sorry, couldn't get what you are trying to say